# Node.js - writeHead to set both "Location" and "Set-Cookie"

Tags: node.js

In node.js(running this in Connect.js), I am able to set ether the Location or Set-Cookie with writehead, but not both at the same time. Currently, the below sets the cooke but the URL does not get redirected to the new location:

```
function foo(req, res, next) {
    var url = /container-templates/;
    if (url.test(req.url)) {
        console.log(url.test(req.url));
        console.log(req.url);
        res.writeHead(302, ["Location", 'https://staging.dx.host.com' + req.url],
                ["Set-Cookie", "fake-token=5b49adaaf7687fa"]);
        res.end();
    } else { next() }
}
```

On a side note, I am doing this for the learning experience and do not want to use any pre-written plugins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Response#writeHead` expects the headers to be an Object not a list of array arguments.

The [Node HTTP documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers) has the following signature defined:

```
response.writeHead(statusCode, [reasonPhrase], [headers])
```

If you want to pass in multiple headers your code from above should read:

```
response.writeHead(302, {
    Location: 'https://staging.dx.host.com' + req.url',
    'Set-Cookie': 'fake-token=5b49adaaf7687fa'
});
```

The `[]` on the `reasonPhrase` means its optional and infers what you've provided to the function based on the types of the arguments.

Also, you don't need to wrap the `key` part of an object in quotes unless it contains characters that are invalid for variable names (like the `-`.)  And a single `'` will do for all strings -- there is no difference in javascript between `'` and `"`.

Comment: Just to note: I can't set the cookie for the other host on a redirect...on a proxy yes, but not a on redirect

Comment: Yeah I hadn't thought about that but the HTTP spec does not allow that on a 302.